# Console Command to Rename Location?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Is there a console command to rename a building or other marked area? I am going to customize a house using console and put it back onto the xbox (change ownership, add objects, ect.), so I can't use mods.

Comment: What do you mean you want to put it back on Xbox? The console versions don't have a console nor can they run mods (currently) so I'm a little confused about what you're asking...

Comment: I have both the pc version and xbox version- I mainly play on Xbox though. Anything done on console will stay when I transfer the save to xbox. However, playing on Xbox leaves any mods out of the question because they change the game itself, not the save file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, no, none of the place names in the game can be modified (except by changing the locale, which is different). The [console commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) that affect location are:

GetLocationCleared <id>
SetLocationCleared <id> 1
ResetInterior <id>
coc <cellname>
cow <worldspace> <cell x, cell y>

(The latter two stand for Center on Cell/World.)

None of those provide much control over the properties of a location, just toggling some flags or placing the character.